# Increase the default width of the SiteXML(Left Navigation Pane in dashboard) in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, sitemap

Is there any way by which I can increase the default width of the CRM 2011 SiteMap, i.e. the left navigation pane in the dashboard?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just came to know this is not supported.